# Expand grid cell on wp7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I am setting up a 3 x 3 grid on a wp7 using `<grid>` and `<row/columnDefinitions>` for size. When someone taps on a cell, I want the cell to take up the entire 3 x 3 space (so now the grid is 1 x 1). Also when this happens, I need to animate this as a slow zoom up or something similar.

Any ideas where i should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer but can note down my initial thoughts that could help you.

It appears the Height and Width properties of RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition are Dependency properties which means you can animate them with a storyboard. You could either create nine storyboards (one for each grid) or one storyboard that you modify in code for the animation required.

Another approach could be using the Visual State Manager, with separate states for each cell you could achieve the effects you're after by altering the row and column definitions. Bit tedious as well since you'll need ten states.